# how should I add SPNEGO authentication to a servlet without 3party libs

Tags: java, servlets, spnego

I'm looking for a generic (no Filter or frameworks) way to add SPNEGO authentication support to a servlet.

I have looked a little at JAAS, but been unable to find a sample on how to require SPNEGO from a servlet client/consumer.

I'm not interested in the HTTP Servlet Filter.
The solution needs to be in a container independent way.

I would prefer if respondents build their answer/hint on personal hands-on, but I would appreciate anything that can get me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you waste your time? Take a library simply works: http://tomcatspnegoad.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thank you for answering.

I do not like to waste my time, so I asked here to be pointed in the right direction.
Your library looks very cool - and even as it is targeting a specific container (Tomcat) and using integration that breaks in higher versions of this container - it does give me a lot of code to look at.

The reason why I'm on the step of taking the deep dive into this topic is that I'm currently working with a API management gateway that is written in Java but needs to be handling SPNEGO due to a Microsoft environment.

Comment: @citywall, the code break is just because this has been changed in Tomcat 7. I will provide a Tomcat 8 version in the near future. I am using this code for years now in a Active Directory env.

Comment: @citywall, how did you get things done then? I am having same requirement but I have Apache karaf and OSGI environment to work in.

Comment: @AnilBhargava - it is about 3-4 years back, so I do not remember all the details. I think that I had to solve the problem in some other way than I wanted to, and it was primarily part of doing a testing-endpoint for comparison, so I might have ended up abandoning the idea or changing the platform for this.
Sorry :(